# How to use sagepay gayteway in react native app?

Tags: react-native, payment-gateway

I want to integrate sagepay gateway in my react native app. I have tried it but can't succeeded. is there any way to use sagepay in my react native app without using I-frame .

Answer (score 2):

I did it using webview.

```
 return (
      <WebView
        domStorageEnabled={ true }
        javaScriptEnabled={ true }
        source={{uri: url}} />
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WebView` or `CustomTabs` (for Android) or `SafariView` (for iOS).

Then use callbacks methods to handle events. For iOS `SafariView` will be best option. https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-safari-view

For Android, you need to create some native modules to handle `CustomTabs` via your JS code.

Now this problem is reduced to same as implementing gateway on website, which is easy enough, most gateway have awesome docs on that.

Basically when user wants to pay then redirect him to WebView, let him to make transaction in the browser, then on gateway callback, take him back to the app.

Comment: WebView is not working in android. actually i am working in android and WebView is not working here. how can i use ?
its hardly required for me

Comment: I want, when I click on checkout than its redirect to sagepay payment gateway but not to redirect on browser.

Comment: How can i use external webpage in my app

Comment: I have tried WebView but its nor working for me. can you please tell me how can i do this

Comment: `WebView` will not be good choice. Use `SafariView` for & `CustomTabs` for Android. You can take reference from https://GitHub.com/zulip/zulip-mobile. We have used them to implement oAuth login (Google & Gitub). Let me know in case you face any problem.